# What does the following notation mean: $ x \in [-1, 1]^{N}$?

Tags: notation

What does the following notation mean: $ x \in [-1, 1]^{N}$ ? Does it mean that $x$ is either 1 or -1 ?

Comment: It means that $x$ is a sequence of $N$ elements, each of which lies in the interval $[-1, 1]$.

Comment: Ordinarily this would mean that $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N)$ where each $x_i \in [1,1]$. That is, $x$ is a member of the $N$ dimensional hyper cube centered at $0$ where each side length is $2$.

Comment: It's difficult to impossible to be sure what it means without any context. Could you add the context to the question?